# Problem with printing from 2 processes simultaneous

Tags: c

i have 2 processes that each run his threads and there are prints that happens simultaneously and run each other.
how can i protect the prints that only when one is done the other will begin? is there some way to send mutex between two processes?

Comment: On Windows, use a named mutex. On Linux, you can place a mutex in a shared memory segment. This is however problematic if both processes need to ensure it is initialized, because they need to synchronize this somehow, and to synchronize things, they need a mutex. It is better to use semaphores for this.

Answer (score 0):

try using OpenMutex function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-openmutexw

you can ***create*** the Mutex in the main process
and ***open*** the mutex in the sub process